Graphical Glitch with Certain Applications in Ubuntu on VirtualBox
I'm running Ubuntu on Oracle VM VirtualBox, and everything works fine except for certain applications like the File Manager, Rubbish Bin, and Settings. When I open these, instead of the full application, I only see a flickering white square that leaves traces of itself when I move the window. Despite this issue, other applications like Firefox, Terminal, and App Center open and function normally.
Info:

Host Machine's Graphics Card: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4070 Laptop
VirtualBox Graphics Controller: VMSVGA with 3D acceleration
Guest Ubuntu Version: 24.04
Kernel Version: 6.8.0-40-generic


Ubuntu does not have a rubbish bin, Windows does. You describe a graphical issue but fail to have any graphics info in the question. Please edit the question and add the make and model of the graphics card and the kernel being used.

@DavidDE I have it for some reason. (image). I’ve added the graphics info to my question. Let me know if you need anything else.
